# Likert scale statistical analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert

I have 2 groups that have completed several Likert (1-5) surveys and I want to test if there is a significant difference in the responses between the 2 groups for each survey. However the number of responses vary between the 2 groups, where group 1 always has many more responses compared to group 2. This is often roughly 1000 vs 100 responses but can sometimes be as low as 500 vs 10. I'm currently using a Mann Whitney U for each of the surveys as I'm not interested in comparing between surveys

Firstly, is the Mann Whitney U suitable for this hypothesis? Secondly, is there any issue having unbalanced responses between the two groups, especially when one of the groups response rate is low <10 and <5% of that survey's responses.

Comment: I can't answer the second question concerning the balance, but, since your data is ordinal, maybe an Ordinal Regression (in R, the clm() family, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf)  or a Kruskall-Wallis (tho I've seen some discussions concerning the later)  could be more suitable than a Mann Whitney U test

Comment: Have you considered using multiple group confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) or IRT?